# Hibernate - One-to-one mapping with column name

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have two tables:

- CUSTOMERS: ID (key)
- PERSONAL_DATA: ID (key), CUSTOMER_ID

Is it possible to create **XML** configuration:

- relation one-to-one CUSTOMERS.ID -> PERSONAL_DATA.CUTOMER.ID
- property of type PERSONAL_DATA in CUSTOMERS pojo class?

Comment: @AmitJoshi Ok, what information do you need? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, xmls may look like:

1. CUSTOMERS xml:

```html
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_CUSTOMERS" table="CUSTOMERS" catalog="YOUR_DATABASE_NAME">
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="id" />
   <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <one-to-one name="PERSONAL_DATA" class="QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_PERSONAL_DATA"
   cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

2. PERSONAL_DATA xml:

```html
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_PERSONAL_DATA" table="PERSONAL_DATA"
          catalog="YOUR_DATABASE_NAME">
        <id name="customer_id" type="java.lang.Integer">
          <column name="customer_id" />
            <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">CUSTOMERS</param>
         </generator>
      </id>
        <one-to-one name="CUSTOMERS" class="QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_CUSTOMERS"
           constrained="true">
        </one-to-one>
        <property name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
        </property>
          
      </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Is it your solution based on new column added to CUSTOMERS (customer_id) ? This table does not has it :)

Comment: I took customer_id, as primary key. In your case customer_id should be replaced with id i.e. primary key of customer table. Its not a new column

Comment: Thanks, I will check your solution as as possible

Comment: <property name="customer_id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="customer_id" />
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">CUSTOMERS</param>
            </generator>
        </property>

Element 'generator' is not allowed there.

Comment: oh yes.. generator is allowed in case of 'id', I have edited my answer, but in this case the key of PERSONAL_DATA will be customer_id and you will not reuquire separate 'id' column

Comment: Thank you for verification.